# Specify alternative to build.gradle in intelij 2019.3.x

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Gradle 6 allows the user to use alternative build file:

```
gradlew -b my-build.gradle
```

How can I tell intellij idea to use an alternative build file for an imported Gradle module. It seems like it always defaults to build.gradle? I could not see any project configuration in the Gradle panel?

...As a workaround, it looks like IntelliJ will respect your `settings.gradle` file, so you can specify the alternative build file there:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-project'
rootProject.buildFileName = 'my-build.gradle'
```

Comment: For the importing you select the speicfic file in Gradle tool window or when importing an existing project via File | Open action and select the file.the specific

Comment: Andrey, this is exactly what I did - in the Module import dialog I selected my-build.gradle file, but when the import was done, in my Gradle pane I see the tasks from build.gradle, not my-build.gradle. Refreshing the Gradle pane did not change anything. Is this a bug in Intellij 2019.3?